# How do I put a link in the middle of a paragraph with HAML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

How do I create this:

```
<p>
  I would like to make a <a href="foo.html">link</a> in my Rails app.
</p>
```

with HAML?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1.

```
%p
  I would like to make a
  %a
    link
  in my Rails app.
```

2.

```
%p
  I would like to make a <a href="#">link</a> in my Rails app.
```

Comment: Thanks! I must need more coffee. It was the return after the %p that I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 16):

The "pure" HAML way:

```
%p
  I would like to make a 
  %a{:href => "foo.html"} link
  in my Rails app.
```

Using the Rails `link_to` helper:

```
%p
  I would like to make a 
  =link_to "link", "foo.html"
  in my Rails app.
```

Comment: For the record, I was originally using link_to :-) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

If you know your routes, then you can do this:

```
%p
  I would like to make a #{link_to "link", foo_path} in my Rails app.
```

Pretty simple. Just wrap your Ruby syntax with `#{}`.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend reading Chris Eppstein's post ["Haml Sucks for Content"](http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content/), and using something like Markdown or Textile to handle inline markup. I'm a big fan of Haml for document structure and a simple link in a paragraph is simple enough, but Haml starts to get out of control pretty fast.

Comment: I like that way of putting it: Haml is great for structure.